# Android reading text file and splitting

Tags: java, android, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to read a text file that contains integers and store them into a 2d array.
The problem is splitting.
I can read:

```
0 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 0
```

just fine and any numbers 0-9 but I have numbers exceeding 9 (10, 100, 1000).
My method:

```
int[][] mapArray = new int[11][8];
    AndroidFileIO file = new AndroidFileIO(context.getAssets());
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = file.readAsset("maps/map.txt");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("android", "could not load file");
    }
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is);
    scanner.useDelimiter(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            mapArray[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
            Log.d("android", "" + mapArray[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

So I tried using a delimiter and not it hangs and tells me i'm getting a type mismatch?
Any solutions on splitting integers when reading files?

Comment: put this line if(mScanner.hasNext()) before  mapArray[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
 might work, also provide your logcat

Comment: 07-29 03:29:27.569: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5933): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 10
07-29 03:29:27.569: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5933): java.util.InputMismatchException
07-29 03:29:27.569: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1025)
07-29 03:29:27.569: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:1373)
07-29 03:29:27.569: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5933):     at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:1337)

Comment: have you tried the method that I mentioned in above comment

Comment: yes I have. Doesn't seem to change a thing =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out to use this as my delimiter:

```
    scanner.useDelimiter("[\\s,\r\n]+");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression to retrieve the numbers:

```
final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
final Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(content);
while (matcher.find()) {
  final String numberAsString = matcher.group(0);
  final Integer number = Integer.valueOf(numberAsString);
  //do something with number
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Pattern and Matcher and would like to stick with what I am using if at all possible.

Comment: This is just a simple and powerful way to search a text for a patterns based on a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like here you are using ',' as delimiter, But in the input that you have mentioned in the questions there are spaces between the numbers. So `scanner.nextInt()` is trying to convert space character into int, and hence the type mismatch.

[EDIT]

Then your new line character is being read by the `scanner.nextInt()`. Add a check for `'\n'`
and ignore it when you are reading the characters.

Comment: the file is actually something like: 0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1, and then new line and repeat. I am thinking it has to do with the new line?

Answer (score 0):

depending on your purpose, you could read each line in the file as a string,
and then split it.

```
String line = bufferedReader.readLine();   // line is something like "1 2 3"
String[] row = line.split("\\s+");         // got array ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Then it is easier to map each Array element to the destination array.
And and you need Integer.parseInt() to get the integer value.

Comment: Is there a big difference in speed?

Comment: Sorry, I never test it. but since Alex Answer compile the regex once, his code might be faster.